# What's the best way to write a command-line app in Java?

Tags: java, command-line

Okay, I know there are probably a dozen ways to solve this, but I am looking for either a skeleton app or some sort of tutorial that will explain the best way to write a framework for creating Java-based command-line tools.  If my program requires a lot of switches/options/etc., what's the best way to handle all of them?

How do you decide which stuff should be placed into an options/settings file, and which stuff gets put on the command line?  Any sort of sample code would be great, that way I can put my time more towards the central focus of my app rather than the command-line plumbing.

Comment: I found [this][1]. What do you guys think? [1]:http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16715

Answer (score 12):

I also suggest looking at JCommander (http://jcommander.org/), written by the author of TestNG. I have used it successfully in many command line applications.

Answer (score 4):

> How do you decide which stuff should be placed into an options/settings file, and which stuff gets put on the command line?

There's no such dilemma, many things are useful in both places. With the settings file you let the user define defaults and with the command line you let the user override them. Of course, there are cases when only one of the two makes sense, but I'd take providing both as the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer seems to cover what you want to know for writing the app. As for your question about what should go in config files and what should be command line options I would recommend this. If the option is something that is likely to have the same value most of the time put it in a config. If its something that changes frequently make it an option, but remember options SHOULD be optional, try not to create a program that someone has to type in allot of required stuff to make it do it's base function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure if the program I need is going to be used by a human or by a batch-file or some other automated server process.  But I'll heed your advice.  Also, what should I do if a particular command has a lot of data to be passed in? Putting it all on the command line may be too much, so I am thinking about passing in a filename on the command line and then let the program read in the file.

Comment: If it's not human input, I wouldn't create the extra file unless you wanted it for a log or something. Your just creating extra steps that will probably lead to headaches, IMO . It might help us to know the nature of your program.